# The ordering of the permission buttons is not intuitive on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, ios-permissions

I've built an app that needs permissions from the user. The permission to access the current location and the permission to send the user push notifications. It works well, but the ordering of the permission buttons is very confusing for our users. Look at this:

[image: "Allow" is primary action and "Not allow" is secondary]
[image: "Not Allow" is primary action and "Allow" is secondary]

The buttons for "Allow" and "Not allow" are swapped. That leads to a bad user experience.
Do you have any idea how I can influence the ordering of those buttons?
The permission dialog is rendered by the iOS system. I'm using Flutter 2.5.3.

Comment: What version of iOS are you running that on?  That location permission dialog is not the current iOS location permission dialog. The current iOS location permission dialog has options for "allow once" "allow while using the app" and "deny". It also includes an option for precise location on/off. Or are you using a web view in your app?

Comment: The screenshots are made on iOS 12.5.5.

Comment: Ah, ok.  That is quite an old version and the dialogs have changed significantly. There is no way to change the order of the buttons. I suspect the ordering is deliberate such that the top option is the "safe" option for the user. If it's any consolation, the number of users you will have on iOS 12 is probably less than 1%